# Multiplicities of zeros of the polynomial $p(z)=1+2z^4+\frac 7 {10}z^{10}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How many zeros does $p(z)=1+2z^4+\frac{7}{10}z^{10}$ have in the unit disc ? Determine multiplicities of these zeros.

Let , $f(z)=2z^4$ and $g(z)=1+\frac{7}{10}z^{10}$.

Then, on $|z|=1$ ,  $|g(z)|\le 1+\frac{7}{10}|z|^{10}<2=|f(z)|$.

So, by Rouche's theorem , $p(z)$ has $4$ zeros in $|z|<1$.

> Trouble to find multiplicities.

Suppose $\alpha$ be a zero  of $p(z)$ in $|z|<1$ of multiplicity $2$.

Then , $p(\alpha)=0$ and $p'(\alpha)=0$ which implies, $1+2\alpha^4+\frac{7}{10}\alpha^{10}=0$         .....$(1)$

and $8\alpha^3+7\alpha^{9}=0$.

So ,  $\alpha^6=-8/7$

If we can show that  this value of $\alpha$ does not satisfy equation $(1)$ then can we say that all roots are distinct ?

$$OR$$Any other way to show whether the roots are distinct or NOT.

Comment: May be it would simpler find all roots explicitly? This is quadratic equation respect to $z^8$, and $z^8=(3-\sqrt{13})/2$ are roots with $|z|<1$

Comment: @  Michael Galuza) Well..As the equation is a quadratic equation of $z^8$ so you can find out the roots explicitly...But I want the general case..

Comment: What do you mean by “general case”?

Comment: @ Michael Galuza) General case means , when we can not solve the equation explicitly then??

Comment: Why did you replace the question with a different one? Michael Galuza's helpful comments look very strange now.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen) I replace it , because I asked  Michael Galuza a question , but I didn't get any answer for a long time...

Comment: Ok. Not sure that changing the question is going to help you to get one, but it does look like no harm was done, as the only answer is to the newer version.

Comment: You can always run Euclid's algorithm (in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}[z]$) to calculate $\gcd(p(z),p'(z))$. If the answer comes out as $1$, then you know that there will be no multiple zeros. If the answer is non-constant, then the zeros of the greatest common divisor are exactly zeros of multiplicity $>1$.

Comment: My answer to the question was deleted. The one can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chm3ggg0yeprzu0/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-08-20%2013.32.44.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 2):

Answering the newer version with $p(z)=1+2z^4+\dfrac7{10}z^{10}$.

A general fact (valid in all fields, not just that of complex numbers) is that a zero of multiplicity $>1$ is a common zero of both $p(z)$ and $p'(z)$. IOW it is a zero of the greatest common divisor $d(z):=\gcd(p(z),p'(z))$.

That GCD can be very efficiently calculated with Euclid's algorithm (for the purposes of this question [Wikipedia on polynomial GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) is more useful than the one explaining Euclid's algorithm for calculating the GCD of integers - algebraically they have a common root).

Here $p'(z)=8z^3+7z^9$. Any common factor of $p$ and $p'$ is also a factor of
$$
r_1=p-\frac 1{10}z\ p'=1+z^4(2-\frac8{10})+z^{10}(\frac7{10}-\frac7{10})=1+\frac65z^4.
$$

I'm sure that you can find the zeros of $r_1(z)$, and test whether they can be zeros of $p(z)$. If not, you can continue, and calculate the remainder $r_2$ of the long division of $p'$ by $r_1$. If $r_2\neq0$, then it will be of a lower degree than $r_1$, and you can use that instead.

Alternatively you can substitute $z^4=-5/6$ to the original equation $p(z)=0$. You get a quadratic that's easy to manage.